# Why can't I store email bodies in a relational database?

Tags: sql, relational-database

Say I define a table `users` with a column for email messages where I dump the whole message as a string.

It would be ugly and messy but would it work? What would be the consequence of doing this?

I am asking because I read that unstructured data cannot be stored in a relational database and an email body is highly unstructured but it in itself is just a string.

Comment: Email body can have images and some attachment. If those things not included and contain text only. Then it is possible to store in column of sql table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can put the whole email into a "text" or "string" column in the database.

Even better, many databases support text search functionality.  So you could build a text index and be able to search through the email body efficiently.

The downside is that the rows are bigger, which can slow down using the table.  If the emails are repeated, then you probably want a separate table for the emails, with an id representing the text.  Another table would show which users received which email.

Comment: Well this has me confused a bit. If I say unstructured data cannot be stored in my database, does mean if I define a column for email bodies then emails arent really unstructured anymore (in my database)? Edit: "Unstructured" only refers to data that I havent defined in my database, so if I store "red car pictures" in my database, "blue cars pictures" are automatically seen as unstructured?

Comment: @katrinsterner . . . I'm not sure what you are referring to in terms of what you have read.  "Structured" in a database context typically refers to entities and attributes.  The email attribute is a string -- long and complex -- but still a string, and it would be stored as a string (or JSON or something similar) in a database column.